# Matrix Representation of non-hermitian Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Can anyone explain how can I represent my hamiltonian as a matrix?

Hamiltonian $H=p^2 + i\sin x$   (non-hermitian)

As I want to find its eigenvalues, I need to have the hamiltonian in matrix form. Or is there a way to find eigenvalues without having the matrices?

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried first getting the matrix representation of elementary Hamiltonians with periodic potentials?  Have you tried solving the associated differential equations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the entire real line, you can use Fourier transforms to get a matrix with a continuous infinity of of rows and columns. If on a finite interval commensurate with the period of the sine, use a Fourier series. In each case the matrix will be infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I have just started studying about such hamiltonians so I don't have the knowledge of techniques that you suggested. Could you please explain it elaborately?

Comment: I fear that if you do not know these techniques, you are out if your depth. What is your knowledge background? Have you studied any quantum mechnics or eigenvalue problems for differential opertors?

Comment: I should add that solutions of the associated differential equation will be Mathieu functions with an imaginary parameter, and you will need to know Bloch's theorem for periodic potentials.

Comment: @quantum_curiosity You might want to refer to previous readings for this or many of your other questions:  it is difficult to pinpoint the difficulty when broad topics such as matrix representations or hermiticity or dimensions are covered in many textbooks on QM.